# yii columns to models

Tags: php, yii

Currently using Yii framework. I am trying to select a columns in one table and make it an array of a different model.  I think yii has a method of doing this, and was wondering what it was.  My tables are shown blow:

tables

ticket

ID | code

picks

ID | ticket_ID  | Points

I have a list of picks.  And I would like to make it into a list of tickets.
Any help would be nice.  thank you

```
public static function get_tickets_pick($Points){
    $picks = Picks::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('Points'=>$Points));
    $tickets = //yii command to convert it
    return $tickets;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the function relation.
In the Picks Model:

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'ticket' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Tickets', 'ticket_ID'),
    );
}
```

Tickets Model

```
public function relations()
{
    return array(
        'picks' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Picks', 'ticket_ID'),
    );
}
```

Then, magically:

```
public static function get_tickets_pick($Points){
    $picks = Picks::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('Points'=>$Points));
    foreach($picks as $pick){
        $tickets[] = $pick->ticket;
    }
    return $tickets;
}
```